# Getting notifications in MUC with ejabberd and converse.js

Tags: ejabberd, converse.js

I'm using ejabberd as xmpp server, and I'm trying to receive some notification from a multi user chat room when the user is not present at the chatroom , to accomplish this I've subscribed the user to the chat room, but at the end, on the frontend I use converse.js, there is no such notification.

The ejabberd endpoint get_subscribers returns the desired user. But as I said there is no notification in the client.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do, but you would need a Push server to work with ejabberd mod_push and a client that supports it. I also assume that you are using MucSub.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond Thx for the comment, I asked about the client if supports the MucSub and it not. Conversejs 4.2. I will change the solution to open and minimize all the bookmarks and just wait for the notifications of new messages.